# Asynchronous connection

Tags: c#, networking, asynchronous

I need to use the function BeginConnect but then i havent been able to find any vivid example of its usage. So i want to have my callback function as say 'funct' how would the syntax be?

The syntax is given in a lot of sites but i am getting a few errors when i use the method.
Just send in a line that shows the usage of the method call.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are talking about Socket.BeginConnection in the .NET framework. The MSDN documentation contains a couple of examples.  This [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx) shows a complete example of how to use the asynchounous functions of socket.